# winpty: error: cannot start xampp/php/php.exe Showing internal error: agent timed out

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php-7, xampp

How to solve this Magento 2.3.6 error?

I have installed it on the XAMPP server

> winpty: error: cannot start 'D:/xampp/php/php.exe bin/magento
> indexer:reindex': internal error: agent timed out

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below process to reindex from the command line.
At first please check which drive you have installed XAMPP. (Ex. C:). So if you have XAMPP installed in drive C:
go to the command line (CMD) - type -
cd
Now you will go to root drive C:

Now you have to go over on Magento2 root folder so you can use the below command

> cd C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2folder

Now you are on your Magento2 root folder

Now type the following command

> php bin\magento indexer:reindex

One other method you can follow like this

1. Open Xampp control panel
2. Click on the Shell button
3. Now you have to move on Magento2 root folder so same you can type the following command

> cd C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2folder

Now you are on your Magento2 root folder

Now type the following command

> php bin\magento indexer:reindex